# When useing jquery slide some of the css doesnt apply until after the slide

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, html, jquery-slider

I'm making an html5 website. the page I'm encountering the issue is http://yamikowebs.com/blog.php
right now I'm working on the copy/paste link. when you click it the other links slide in from the left.
for some reason my anchors are underlined and display inline until the animation is done. is there a fix for this?

```
$(".blogLinks>article").hide(0);//hides all boxes
$("#blogDirectory>ul>li").click(function()
{
    switch ($(this).index())//check which one
    {
        case 1:
            $("[title=0]").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);//animate it
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the animation is taking place, your div is wrapped in a temporary div with a class of `ui-effects-wrapper`. Once the animation is complete, your `article` element appears as a child of `blogLinks` and is styled appropriately, but until then, the `article` element is a child of `.ui-effects-wrapper`.

Try applying the same style to `.ui-effects-wrapper a`

Comment: (+1) or just using a class to select the anchors directly.

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize that jquery gave a wrapper with css applied to it. is there a way to views these in firebug at specific points in the animation?

Comment: You can step through the specific javascript calls in firebug, but in this case, if you simply monitor the source code for the `div` that slides out, you'll see firebug update in realtime and highlight the newly added code.

Comment: Is there a way to not do it in real time and possible stop it when the wrapper is added? I know how to put stops in the script tab and see the real time changes. the real time changes are to fast to read.